# Applying If Then logic to a dataframe R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I think I may have bit off more than I can chew. I am trying to apply a logical equation to a set of data based on a few factors to develop a final estimate for each year. I got all my data in the same place but now am struggling to manipulate it appropriately.

Long short of it I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
YEAR    ID    V1   V2   V3   Delta1   Delta2
1990    A     3    NA   NA   NA       NA
1991    A     5    2    NA   2        NA
1992    A     7    4    6    2        2
1990    B     3    1    NA   NA       NA
1991    B     5    2    NA   2        1
1992    B     7    1    NA   2        -1
etc
```

I want to apply the following logic to calculate a new column for each row:

For each ID in 1990

```
if there is a V3 value that will be selected    
else if    
if there is a V2 value that will be selected for the new column    
else
they are assigned the value of V1 (V1 is always populated).
```

For each proceeding year an ID is assigned a value based on

```
if there is a V3 value it equals V3 * Delta1
else if
the ID has never had a V3 value the calculated value will equal V2
else if
it has had a V3 but just not this year it equals the years previous calculated value for that ID * Delta2
else
the calculated value simply equals the previous years calculated value * Delta1
```

I know how to apply if else logic but I am lost in how to do so iteratively through years for each ID against the data frame. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:

Ideally output would look as such

```
YEAR    ID    V1   V2   V3   Delta1   Delta2   CalculateColumn
1990    A     3    NA   NA   NA       NA        3
1991    A     5    2    NA   2        NA        4
1992    A     7    4    6    2        2         6
1990    B     3    1    NA   NA       NA        1
1991    B     5    2    NA   2        1         2
1992    B     7    1    NA   2        -1        4
etc
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the expected output including new column based on your sample.

Comment: Added, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You may try looking into the `case_when` function within the `dplyr` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So didn't find a perfect answer but managed a work around.

Each ID is present in the same number of years, so I was able to order the dataframe and then loop through the rows by simple counting.

```
db = db[order(db$ID, db$Year),]
```

First I assigned V1 to all 1990 values:

```
db$CalculatedColumn[db$Year == 1990] = db$V1[db$Year == 1990])
```

From there I was able to craft any loop logic I wanted.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(db)) {
  if(db$Year[i] == 1990) {
    if(!is.na(db$V3[i])){
      db$CalculatedColumn[i] = db$V3[i] * db$Delta1
      } else {NULL}
  } else {
    if(!is.na(db$V3[i])){
     db$CalculatedColumn[i] = db$V3[i] * Delta1[i]
    } else if(!is.na(db$V2[i])){
      db$CalculatedColumn[i] = db$V2[i]  * db$Delta2[i]
    } else {
      db$CalculatedColumn[i] = db$CalculatedColumn[i-1]  * db$Delta1[i]
    }
  }
}
```

Note this logic is slightly different from what I asked as my end need changed, and it took a long time to run, there is definitely a better way to do this.